# Sum textboxes RDLC Report

Tags: rdlc

I have a table and I want to sum the total of the 5 textboxes,

I tried:

```
=ReportItems!ttw1.Value + ReportItems!ttw2.Value + ReportItems!ttw3.Value + ReportItems!ttw4.Value + ReportItems!ttw5.Value
```

But the result is odd: (last row)

[image: Table]

Tried to use Formatnumber but returns `Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are being concat as `String`, you need to cast them into `integer`/`decimal`/`double` before adding them.

`CDbl` will cast them into `double`.

```
=CDbl(ReportItems!ttw1.Value) + CDbl(ReportItems!ttw2.Value) ...
```

Comment: Amazing. Works perfectly.